# Hive - Create partitioned table conditionally

Tags: hadoop, hive, partitioning, create-table

I'm trying to create a Hive table partitioned by rage of time (unix time).
All I could find is how to make a partition for each value. But I want to partition by rage of values. I tried something like:

```
CREATE TABLE testing.test 
  (uuid bigint , userid varchar(100),username varchar(100))

  PARTITIONED BY (uuid bigint uuid>1000 and uuid<2000,uuid >2000 and uuid <3000)
```

But it's obviously didn't work. Any Ideas for the correct syntax?

Comment: Not supported ...

Comment: (uuid>1000 and uuid<2000) is a boolean expression. You can create partition field `uuid_1000_2000` for example and load into it using your expression.

Comment: I'll do that, Thanks!